# Problema na View (detalhes)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou a repetir a Letragrupo na View, como posso usar o ".first" na query no controlador?

Erro na View:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeVdY.png

View(detalhes):

```
@model IEnumerable<WebAppCatechesis2.ViewModels.GrupoViewModel>
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">

                <dt>
                    Catequizandos:
                </dt>
                <table>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NomeCatequizando)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
                <dt>
                    LetraGrupo:
                </dt>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LetraGrupo)                               
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                }

            </dl>
```

Controlador:

```
public ActionResult Detalhes(int? id)
        {
            var grupo = db.Grupo.Where(g => g.GrupoID ==id).FirstOrDefault();

            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            //query para recolher as nomes dos catequizandos pertencentes ao grupo selecionado
            var queryNomeCatequizandos = (from g in db.Grupo
                                          join i in db.Inscricao on g.GrupoID equals i.GrupoID
                                          join c in db.Catequizando on i.CatequizandoID equals c.CatequizandoID
                                          join p in db.Pessoa on c.CatequizandoID equals p.PessoaID
                                          where g.GrupoID == i.GrupoID 
                                          && i.CatequizandoID == c.CatequizandoID 
                                          && c.CatequizandoID == p.PessoaID 
                                          && g.GrupoID == id
                                          select new GrupoViewModel
                                          {
                                              GrupoID = i.GrupoID ?? 0,
                                              NomeCatequizando = p.Nome,
                                              LetraGrupo = g.LetraGrupo,
                                              Sala = g.Sala                                                                                  
                                          });

            if (queryNomeCatequizandos == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(queryNomeCatequizandos.ToList());
        }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class GrupoViewModel
    {
        public int GrupoID { get; set; }
        public String AnoPastoral { get; set; }
        public String HoraInicio { get; set; }
        public String DiaSessao { get; set; }
        public String AnoCatequese { get; set; }
        public String LetraGrupo { get; set; }
        public String Sala { get; set; }
        public String Observacoes { get; set; }
        public String NomeCatequizando { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Ué... se eu entendi bem queryNomeCatequizandos é uma lista.. e você tenta pegar 1 propriedade de 1 objeto dentro da lista... nao teria que fazer um foreach?

Answer (score 1):

Jovem, você não pode acessar diretamente uma propriedade em uma lista.
Observe que sua view tem como módel IEnumerable

```
@model IEnumerable<WebAppCatechesis2.ViewModels.GrupoViewModel>
```

E logo abaixo você tenta acessar uma propriedade dessa lista sem especificar o elemento, você está acessando como se fosse apenas um GropoViewModel. O erro está aqui:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LetraGrupo)
```

O erro também irá acontecer em todas as linhas abaixo:

```
                    <dt>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LetraGrupo)
                    </dt>
                    <dt>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Sala)
                    </dt>
                    <dt>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Sala)
                    </dt>
```

Edite sua view e coloque dessa maneira que deve funcionar:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebAppCatechesis2.ViewModels.GrupoViewModel>
   <div class="panel-body">
                <table>
                   @foreach (var grupo in Model)
                  {
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => grupo.LetraGrupo)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => grupo.LetraGrupo)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => grupo.Sala)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => grupo.Sala)
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => grupo.NomeCatequizando)
                    </td>
                   </tr>

                   }
                 </table>  
            </div>
```

Comment: Sim já tinha percebido isso, o que eu quero é apenas um registo. Por exemplo está acontecer isto na View. "Letra Grupo : A A A A A" ` fiz isto no controlador e não funciona `LetraGrupo = g.LetraGrupo.first`.

Comment: Para ser mais especifico. Problema: http://i.imgur.com/7t8AOJI.png?1